# Who is the hero of my every day?

Tags: riddle

*Part of the [everyday object series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=body%3A%22everyday%20object%20series%22%20is%3Aquestion)*

> You are the hero of my every day,
>   scaring the black demons away.
>   In tiny circles, round you march,
>   over rows of weapons, strung in an arc.
>   Your own weapon is gentle, does not destroy,
>   but fills me up with frothy joy.

Who is my hero?

Comment: Who or what is the riddle in the perspective of? Any person?

Comment: Could be any person. In fact (hint) it *should* be everyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could the hero of your every day be a

> toothbrush

scaring the black demons away.

> keeping cavities at bay.

In tiny circles, round you march,

> circling around the teeth.

over rows of weapons, strung in an arc.

> the incisors, canines and molars hopefully in an arc.

Your own weapon is gentle, does not destroy,

> the toothbrush and bristles are gentle.

but fills me up with frothy joy.

> frothy toothpaste.

Comment: Congratulations, you are correct! But the black demons refer to ROT13(Pnivgvrf). What do you think about it? Too easy?

Comment: I thought it was sparklingly well written and enjoyed the contrast of weapons and geometric descriptions.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer

You are:

> A cup of coffee, caffeine

You are the hero of my every day
scaring the black demons away.

> Having a cup of coffee in the morning wakes you up, chases away the sleepy feeling

In tiny circles, round you march,

> Tiny circles, coffee cups or espresso cups. Coffee “marches” to fulfill their duty in tiny circular vessels.

over rows of weapons, strung in an arc.

> Not sure on this one yet

Your own weapon is gentle, does not destroy,
but fills me up with frothy joy.

> Caffeine is gentle compared to other drugs, and does not destroy your life when addicted to it. Frothy joy might refer to a latte and the mood altering one experiences when caffeine is being processed by the body.

Comment: Sorry, no. How does a cup of coffee march in circles?

Comment: I read march as a metaphor as in, marching to fulfill their duty. The delivery method is usually a cup (circular)