# The everyday millipede

Tags: riddle, rhyme

*Part of the [everyday object series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=body%3A%22everyday+object+series%22+is%3Aquestion)*

> I'm the everyday millipede, come look at my feet!
>   I put a smile on your face with my frothing stampede.
>   I walk inside you, walk in circles and in lines,
>   My legs can be straight or angled, arranged in different designs.
>   I trample rosy flesh and hardest bones,
>   Yet in every household you'll find my clones.

What is this everyday millipede?

Comment: Following Tom's comment on my answer, this seems to be a duplicate of [one of your own riddles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80498/who-is-the-hero-of-my-every-day)! Due to similarities in the answer and some of the language I've therefore voted to mark it as a duplicate. Shame, 'cause the millipede imagery is nicely poetic! :)

Comment: @Stiv Is it a duplicate just because the answer is the same? I felt that this is indeed a different riddle because the phrases and hints are different.

Comment: Well, on closer reflection there were some unusual key words in common (e.g. 'froth') and it's in the exact same series as the other one with the same answer, rather than just being a random duplicate of another unconnected user's past puzzle. You could probably choose from any number of 'everyday' objects for this series - no need to reuse one really! :) Anyway, this is just my opinion - others can choose to ignore it or agree with it as they like... *EDIT: Don't get me wrong, I like the riddle! I just think it qualifies as a duplicate...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're a:

> **TOOTHBRUSH**

*I'm the everyday millipede, come look at my feet!*

> A toothbrush has many, many bristles, just as a millipede has many, many feet.

*I put a smile on your face with my frothing stampede.*

> Brushing your teeth with a toothbrush and toothpaste causes the paste to *froth* and makes that smile white and new!

*I walk inside you, walk in circles and in lines,*

> This describes good brushing action, with back-and-forth ('lines') and circular motions in your mouth ('inside you').

*My legs can be straight or angled, arranged in different designs.*

> Modern toothbrushes come in so many different designs, ranging from the standard straight-bristled look to designs specifically for targeting particular parts of the mouth and cleaning hard-to-reach places with angled bristles.

*I trample rosy flesh and hardest bones,*

> The toothbrush's bristles (feet) walk on your gums (rosy flesh) and teeth (bones).

*Yet in every household you'll find my clones.*

> Pretty much everybody has one!

Comment: Damn, you are just too fast ;)

Comment: I thought way too complex

Comment: Great descriptions, it's tough deciding if riddle questions with same answer are  duplicates but maybe in this case [Who is the hero of my every day?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80498/who-is-the-hero-of-my-every-day). I'm unsure.

Comment: @Tom Hmmm, given it's the same author and even the same series this strikes me very much as a duplicate! I wonder if Elmy forgot they'd already done this one?

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> A vitamin pill?

I put a smile on your face with my frothing stampede

> When you put it in a glass of water it starts frothing, and you feel better after taking it

I walk inside you, walk in circles and lines

> The vitamins circulate in your blood circle, where some of the arteries are in a line, like from elbow to hand

My legs can be straight or ankled, arranged in different designs

> This refers to the look of the molecules, which can have straight, or ankled connections, depending on the molecule

I trample rosy flesh and hardest bones

> Vitamins are good for your bones and flesh

But in every household, you'll find my clones

> Everyone has vitamin pills at home